# Is there a way to make two parts of the document linked? So that if I change one part of the document the other automatically updates?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am building a template, where the wording is important. And even more important, that the wording is used in the exact same way in another section of the document. (in the review)

I know with the Title property, if you change it in one place it will change in another. But in custom properties, i have trouble replicating this behavior.

This functionality would also need to be repeatable, when I insert a quickpart I would need it to be linked to itself, not the section above.

for instance

| Section # | Subsection # - Objective: [linked text] |
| --- | --- |
| Section 1 |  |
|  | Subsection 1 - Objective: foo |
|  | Subsection 2 - Review: foo |
| Section 2 |  |
|  | Subsection 1 - Objective: bar |
|  | Subsection 2 - Review: bar |

where section 1 is the original entry, and the linked text is foo, and section 2 is the inserted quickpart and the linked text is bar. And every subsequent quickpart entry after that a new linked text property relationship is created. (baz etc...)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Title Document Property Content Control is an example of a Mapped Content Control.

There are fifteen mapped Document Property Content Controls built into Word. They are under the Insert > Quick Parts drop down. Here is [my page on using and repurposing those](http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart). *These are currently only in the Windows desktop version: not directly available in the Mac versions of Word (nor the mobile and web versions. They do work on the Mac versions, though.)*

The advantage of these is that they are built into Word. The disadvantages include that there are only fifteen of these and that all except the Publish Date one are plain text controls.

Any kind of Content Control can be mapped to the XML. Mapping of such controls is described in [this Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Working-with-Word/working-with-content-controls).

While this can be done using vba or through direct editing of XML, I never have done so. Here are free utilities that let you easily create mapped Content Controls or map existing Content Controls.  I have used all three.

- [Content Control Tools by Greg Maxey](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html)
- [Insert Content Controls Add-In by Graham Mayor](http://www.gmayor.com/insert_content_control_addin.htm)
- [Custom Content Control Insert Dialog by Greg Maxey](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/Content_Control_Custom_Insert_Dialog.html)

An advantage of the built-in ones is that they are on an easy-to-use menu under Quick Parts. Greg has developed another free [utility](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html) that lets you create a separate menu under Quick Parts for [Enhanced Document Properties](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/EnhancedDocProp_AddIn.html). Those are similar to the built-in ones.